# How to change SharePoint Datetime Control format

Tags: datetime, sharepoint-2013

I'm using SharePoint datetimecontrol and i want the format YYYY/mm/dd.

I've changed the culture from regional settings and set the localId to 1025 but i'm getting the format always dd/mm/YYYY.

How to change the display to YYYY/mm/dd?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried this way using calculated columns**

[image]

**=TEXT([your column name],"yyyy-mm-dd") use this code**

[image]

*Hope its helpful for you*